# I have a problem with my SQL statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, identity-insert

```
    Threads 
------- 
ThreadID
 UsersID 
Date 
ThreadTitle
 ThreadParagraph 
ThreadClosed 

  Topics 
-----
 TopicsID 
Theme
 Topics 
Date
```

Here is my statement:

```
  StringBuilder insertCommand = new StringBuilder();
    insertCommand.Append("DECLARE @TopicsID int");
    insertCommand.Append("INSERT INTO Topics(Theme,Topics,Date)");
    insertCommand.Append("VALUES(@topic,@subTopic,GETDATE())");
    insertCommand.Append("SET @TopicsID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

    insertCommand.Append("INSERT INTO Threads(UsersID,TopicsID,Date,ThreadTitle,ThreadParagraph,ThreadClosed)");
    insertCommand.Append("VALUES(@uniqueIdentifier,@TopicsID,GETDATE(),@questionTitle,@questionParagraph,0)");
```

I get this:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'INTO'. Must declare the scalar
>   variable "@TopicsID". Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@TopicsID".

Comment: If you take the sql out into SSMS can you execute it successfully?

Comment: Have you trying printing the created query (just before or after) ruuning it?

Comment: After @RQDQ comment, i corrected, and i got the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@TopicsID".
Must declare the scalar variable "@TopicsID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
    `insertCommand.AppendLine`

SQL sees

`DECLARE @TopicsID intINSERT INTO Topics(Theme,Topics,Date) ...`

You need to separate the distinct statements

Comment: That work. wheni put the Declare statment with the insert into statment it worked...!xD

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I notice is:

```
insertCommand.Append("VALUES('@topic,@subTopic,GETDATE()')");
```

might need to be:

```
insertCommand.Append("VALUES(@topic,@subTopic,GETDATE())");
```

It looks like you have some extra single quotes in there.

Comment: I thought it was a good thing to put them :(..even necessary..as it makes everything in the VALUES be in quotes.. or is it only when i put simple values (not functions and variables..e.g. VALUES('Gardening','Tools','08/02/2003');

Comment: Yes, you only put single quotes around them in this case.

Comment: Putting single quotes around characters is how to pass them as a string.  It's the same idea as doing MessageBox("1 + 1") - it will display 1 + 1 in a messagebox instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

You need a **semi-colon** after `DECLARE @TopicsID int`

That will take care of the "incorrect syntax" and declaring the scalar variable.

And I believe that you need to remove the **single quotes** around your three `VALUES`. That is causing it to think you have supplied only one `VALUE` instead of three.

Answer (score 1):

Your single quotes on the last line are wrong - its turning it all onto one string:

Change

```
  insertCommand.Append("VALUES('@uniqueIdentifier,@TopicsID,GETDATE(),@questionTitle,@questionParagraph,0')");
```

to

```
insertCommand.Append("VALUES(@uniqueIdentifier,@TopicsID,GETDATE(),@questionTitle,@questionParagraph,0)");
```